# 32 bit jvm on a 32 bit RHEL PAE system

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have a RHEL 6 32 bit system installed in a 64 bit hardware. The kernel version is,

```
2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.i686
```

I posted a very detailed question and answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/142667/maximum-memory-usable-by-a-32-bit-rhel-6-system). Now, I have the JVM which is also 32 bit. I believe even if I install a 64 bit JVM, I will be allowed to use only upto 3 GB since I have only 32 bit OS.

So, my question is, a single process can have more than 4 GB memory and still be used in a 32 bit system. In a similar manner, if I set my maximum heap size to 2 GB in the 32 bit OS, will I still be able to use the memory?

For instance, if my java application requires 10 GB memory, and I set the maximum heap size to 2 GB, my question is, once the 2 GB is exhausted, will my application terminate or swap the address space and continue working?

I am also interested in knowing a good limit on the maximum heap memory limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**> I believe even if I install a 64 bit JVM,**

No, you can't do this. You can only run 32 bit applications on a 32 bit linux OS - even if the underlying hardware is 64 bits.

**> a single process can have more than 4 GB memory and still be used in a 32 bit system.**

No, a 32 bit linux installation only supports 32 bit applications, and that means you're limited to an address space of max 4GB. For linux, the kernel needs 1 GB of that space. Native libraries, stack space and other things also needs a piece of the address space, leaving you with memory available for the heap of around 2-2.5GB.

The [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) feature enables the OS to utilize more than 4GB of memory in total, but individual processes are still limited to 4 GB of address space.

**>  if my java application requires 10 GB memory, and I set the maximum heap size to 2 GB, my question is, once the 2 GB is exhausted, will my application terminate**

Yes, if the application needs more memory, it will terminate with an [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

**> I am also interested in knowing a good limit on the maximum heap memory limit.**

There is no universal answer - it depends on the application and whatever else you want to run on your system.

Comment: thanks for providing an answer. So the individual process here in my case would be `java -XMX2G` ? Suppose, if this java process exceeds 2 GB, the application will fail? Do the concepts of multi threading do not apply here?

Comment: Yes, it will terminated (added that to the answer). The only thing related to muti-threading here is that each thread needs a stack, which by default is 256kB in the Oracle JVM, and that stack space means less memory available for the heap, and possibly that the heap will be more fragmented, which means large memory allocation might not have any room to be allocated within even if the total free memory is more than what a is needed by a single huge allocation.

Comment: thanks. So practically even if PAE permits me to use the entire 32 GB RAM in the RHEL system, my `java` application cannot run, if it's size is more than 4 GB. Is this correct? Also, if I have a 10 GB file opened using java that means the file reading will also fail?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You can read a 10GB big file, if you read and process it in smaller chunks. But naturally you can't keep the entire 10GB file in memory.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe even if I install a 64 bit JVM, I will be allowed to use only upto 3 GB since I have only 32 bit OS.

You can install it, but it won't run.  Only a 64-bit OS can run a 64-bit application, whether it is a JVM or any other program.

> So, my question is, a single process can have more than 4 GB memory and still be used in a 32 bit system.

Not directly.  A 32-bit program can only use about 1.5 to 3 GB direct depending on the OS.  A program can use a disk cache which is much larger.  It can also use other program which themselves use more memory (in total)

> In a similar manner, if I set my maximum heap size to 2 GB in the 32 bit OS, will I still be able to use the memory?

If you have a 2 GB heap this should be fine so long as the process doesn't exceed how much memory your whole process can use.  The heap is not all the memory used of course.

> if my java application requires 10 GB memory, and I set the maximum heap size to 2 GB, my question is, once the 2 GB is exhausted, will my application terminate or swap the address space and continue working?

If you need more than 10 GB, you should ensure you have at least 12 GB of main memory AND a 64-bit OS.  What will happen if you don't have enough will range from the program running very slow, or your program crashing, or in extreme cases your whole machine will practically stop.

Java applications run very badly once they start swapping.  They either crawl to a stop, or they can practically stop  the machine.

> I am also interested in knowing a good limit on the maximum heap memory limit.

A good limit is less than your main memory size.  The default limit for the server JVM is 1/4 of main memory.  Without more information, I would leave it as it is.

Comment: Lawrrey, Thanks for providing me an elaborate answer. So the setting of maximum java heap size can be thought as below. `java` requests the main memory to reserve a chunk of the memory for program execution.

Comment: @Ramesh A common mistake is to assume that the heap size is all the memory used. It is not.  It is just the size of the heap available to Java programs, but it doesn't include other areas the JVM might use such as stacks, code cache, shared libraries, direct memory buffers.  So yes, the JVM will request the main memory as a continuous region, but it's not the only thing it requests.